# Make openbox window border transparent

Tags: linux, transparency, openbox, lxde

Is there any way to make the windows border/system chrome of a window transparent in openbox?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, the best thing I have been able to find makes the entire window transparent. The only real options are forks of X's.

Check out [transset](http://forchheimer.se/transset-df/).  That's about as far as I was able to find.

Comment: Can't compiz have transparent window borders? I was just wondering if openbox could do the same

Comment: From the ArchLinux Wiki: "Compiz is a compositing window manager. It provides its own window manager, Emerald. Therefore it cannot be used simultaneously with other window managers such as Openbox, Fluxbox, or Enlightenment. Users who want to keep their current window managers and add some effects to it may wish to try Xcompmgr instead. "

Comment: I wasnt trying to make compiz work with openbox, but your info about xcompmgr is great!

Comment: Other options are `compton` & `xcompmgr-dana`